# iOS (jailbroken) Displaying application via SBAppContextHostManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, springboard, cydia-substrate

Basically, I'm trying to display an application using the private API SBAppContextHostManager of SpringBoard. So far, I have this code:

```
SBAppContextHostManager *app = [[objc_getClass("SBAppContextHostManager") alloc] init];

[app setAppBundleID:@"com.apple.springboard"]; // just as an example

[app enableHostingForRequester:@"uniqueID" priority:1];

[app orderRequesterFront:@"uniqueID"];

SBHostWrapperView *view = [app hostViewForRequester:@"uniqueID"];
```

and after which I call

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(c, YES);
[view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

to grab a UIImage of the view containing the application. However, the output of this UIImage is completely blank, which leads me to think that my calls to SBAppContextManager are incorrect, thus leading to a blank SBHostWrapperView. Therefore, how should I display an application in this way?

Comment: Oh, by the way, I've found that SO really isn't the best place to ask MobileSubstrate questions. I just happen to be on here. Most of us jailbreak devs hang out in #theos in irc.saurik.com. Asking questions there will most likely be answered better than asking them here.

Comment: Thanks, just asked another question on there; honestly didn't have a clue that channel existed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get a preview of the application, rendering an SBHostWrapperView won't work. You see, SBHostWrapperViews don't copy the application's render output, it simply provides a different location on the screen for the app to render to.

Instead, you can use `- (SBFullscreenZoomView*)systemGestureSnapshotWithIOSurfaceSnapshotOfApp:(SBApplication*)arg1 includeStatusBar:(BOOL)arg2;` in the `SBUIController` class.

That method returns an SBFullscreenZoomView, a subclass of UIView, with a snapshot of the app provided in arg1. You can use the second snippet of code you provided to get a UIImage of the SBFullscreenZoomView. That should do what you are asking, providing you with a screenshot of only a specific application.

Comment: Cheers, that works well, apart from the resulting image after my code appears to be pixelated slightly as if it were on an SD device. Any ideas on why that may be the case?

Comment: That's quite odd. Are you on a retina device? Also, are you applying any transformations to the image? Try anti-aliasing, possibly?

Comment: Yeah, it's retina with no transforms on the image; I'll try anti-aliasing, then have a play around with the scale

Comment: Sorted it, turns out I was using the wrong scaling; updated question with correct code.